# How can I get a field of WebGlContextAttributes?

Tags: rust, webgl, web-sys

My case is like this, I just want to get the field of `WebGlContextAttributes` struct.

```rust
let antialias_info = gl.get_context_attributes().unwrap();

match antialias_info.antialias {
   // ...
}
```

I get the following error:

```
attempted to take value of method `antialias` on type `web_sys::WebGlContextAttributes` method, not a field.
```

And I have read the doc [WebGlContextAttributes](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.51/web_sys/struct.WebGlContextAttributes.html), but still don't know how to get field value of it.

Comment: its not a field here, looks like you need to use parens

Comment: @DanielA.White That's a setter, not a getter.

Comment: @DanielA.White use parens? What is it mean?

Comment: @KevinReid I know, the stuct WebGlContextAttributes doesnt provider a getter. How should i do to get the field value..

Answer (score 2):

It does look like the [`WebGlContextAttributes`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.WebGlContextAttributes.html) type is solely designed as a builder to be used with [`HtmlCanvasElement::get_context_with_context_options()`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.HtmlCanvasElement.html#method.get_context_with_context_options) but that disregards that it should also be used to get attributes from [`WebGlRenderingContext::get_context_attributes()`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.WebGlRenderingContext.html#method.get_context_attributes). I see you have already created an [issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2747) to address this.

As a workaround, you should be able to use the generic mechanism for getting object properties. From [Accessing Properties of Untyped JavaScript Values](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/accessing-properties-of-untyped-js-values.html) in the wasm-bindgen guide you can use [`js_sys::Reflect::get()`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/latest/js_sys/Reflect/fn.get.html) like so:

```
let attributes = gl.get_context_attributes().unwrap();
let antialias = js_sys::Reflect::get(&attributes, &JsValue::from_str("antialias"))
    .unwrap()
    .as_bool()
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: oh, this is cool. Thanks!